# JUnit 3 and 4 not working on eclipse 4.2

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am trying to learn JUnit and I am not able to make it run.
I tried eclipse 4.2 and Android Developer tools (v22).
I am setting up a simple project with one test case.
I tried with JUnit 4 and 3, but whenever I run the test case as a JUnit test, nothing happens, the console hangs. No output from setup before class, tear down or any method. No results.

Here's a simple screenshot of the project with JUnit 3 (same thing happens with JUnit 4).

[image]

I looked for solutions on the SO and other places but none of them seem to fit my case.
The most common problem is multiple JDKs, where in fact I have a single JDK installed, namely 1.7.
The second common problem is the inclusion of JUnit libraries in the project. As you can see, the library is in fact included. When I go to the run configuration to check the classpath, I don't see JUnit, like in the following screenshot.

[image]

However, even if I add JUnit to the running classpath in the launch configuration, I still have the same issue.

Is there anything I can do to fix it or see what could be the problem?

**Edit:** I am on a mac book air running OS X 10.8

Comment: What's printing inside the JUnit view ( at the right of the Package Explorer in your first screenshot ) ?

Comment: Look at the bottom right corner of the status bar. Is Eclipse running something else in the background that is delaying your JUnit run?

Comment: Nope, nothing running in the background. There was something but I killed it. It was syncing Maven stuff ... It's still hanging: running but no output. I left it there for an hour, but nothing changed.

Comment: Look at the Eclipse Error Log, that may provide some ideas:
Help -> About Eclipse -> Configuration Details -> View Error Log

Comment: There's nothing suspecious that could relate to JUnit ... there are some errors but they are proxy settings errors and mercurial ... very normal for me.

Comment: The weird thing is, it worked out of nowhere yesterday for 2 hours. I closed eclipse, the re-opened it and now it doesn't work. Magic!

Comment: Here are bunch of things to try. Check the eclipse error log... Windows->Show View->Error Log. Try starting eclilpse with the -clean option. eclilpse.exe -clean. Lastly, create a new workspace and reimport your projects. If you keep seeing the hang, perhaps its time to reinstall Eclipse. What you are doing should work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are seeing a hang in Eclipse. Perhaps its your Eclipse installation.

More imporantly, when using JUnit 4, you need to annotate your test cases with @Test. Also your setUp and tearDown methods should be annotated with @Before and @After respectively.

Check this [post](http://cdimascio.wordpress.com/category/java/junit/) for a very simple JUnit test and brief explanation of the basic annoations.

Here is a re-rewrite of your test...

```
public class AA {
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // Runs once before each method annotated with @Test
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        // Runs once after each method annotated with @Test.
    }


    @Test
    public void testZabri() {
        // The Sample Test case
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }


}
```

Comment: I already did that sir. As I explained it doesn't work in both JUnit 3 and 4. I am sorry if the screenshot mislead you, but my implementation for JUnit 4 is exactly like yours.